# Commercial Pilot privileges - scenario confusion

Tags: faa-regulations, commercial-operations, far-91, far-135

Assuming the following variations of a scenario.

1. Your friend wants to pay you to fly them to Martha's Vineyard. You rent the aircraft from a local club.
2. Same as above, except your friend rents the aircraft.

The common explanation is that the first situation is not legal because you are providing both the plane and the pilot, but that the second is, because you are only providing yourself.

This doesn't make sense to me, because:

For the same reasons that you need an operating certificate for 1, you also need an operating certificate for 2.

In situation 1, you are acting as a private carrier, and need an operating certificate for private carriage. 91.501 only applies to large turbine aircraft, and "flying your friend to Martha's Vineyard" is not an exemption under 119.1.

In situation 2, it is still a private carriage operation. There is nothing changed about the situation that would qualify it for an exemption under 119.1. You still need an operating certificate under 119.23(b):

> Each person who conducts noncommon carriage (except as provided in §
> 91.501(b) of this chapter) or private carriage operations for compensation or hire with airplanes having a passenger-seat
> configuration of less than 20 seats, excluding each crewmember seat,
> and a payload capacity of less than 6,000 pounds shall—
>
> (1) Comply with the certification and operations specifications
> requirements in subpart C of this part;
>
> (2) Conduct those operations in accordance with the requirements of
> part 135 of this chapter, except for those requirements applicable
> only to commuter operations; and
>
> (3) Be issued operations specifications in accordance with those
> requirements.

It would seem that you need an operating certificate regardless of who rents the aircraft.

Some say that you don't need an operating certificate in situation 2, because it is a dry lease. However, I haven't found any regulation that exempts a dry lease from getting an operating certificate.

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question...